# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and passing multiple queries at startup

Tags: spring

I am working on some existing application and it loads single DB query at server startup .

Now I want to pass more (may 3-4 queries) in same code instead one query. 
i.e.How I can pass multiple queries in spring

Here is code-

myspring.xml

```
<property name="mypropertyfiles">
    <list>
        <value>test1.properties</value>
        <value>test2.properties</value>
     </list>
</property>

<bean id="mybean" class="com.test.MyBean">
    <constructor-arg><ref-bean="mypropertyfiles"/><const-arg>
    <constructor-arg><ref-bean="dataSource"/><const-arg>
    <constructor-arg><value>select pcode, pname from PRODUCT1</value>  
    // Here only one query. **but I want to pass more queries like** 
    //select  pcode, pname from PRODUCT2,
    //select ocode, oname from ORDER1,
    //select ocode, oname from ORDER2
    <const-arg> <property name="systemPropertiesModeName"  value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
</bean>
```

MyBean.java

```
public  class MyBean extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer 
{

private DataSource dSource;
private String dbQuery;
// this is existing map to store PRODUCT1 table details
Map product1Map = new ConcurrentHashMap(); 
//lly, I will create more product2Map,order1Map , order2Map  to store my 
//queries data from PRODUCT2,ORDER1,ORDER2 tables

// here it is taking only one query.But I want more queries ie list
MyBean (Resource[] resources , DataSource dSource,String dbQuery){
      super();
  setLocations(resources);
  this.dSource=dSource;
  this.dbQuery=dbQuery;
}

@override
public String resolvePlaceholder(String p,Peroperties p){
//some code.....
    loadQuery();
}


 loadQuery(){
    JdbcTemplate j;
    j.execute(dbQuery,.......) // exsiting code has one query only{
    public Map doInPreparestament(Preaprestatement ps){
        rs =ps.executeQuery..
            while(rs.next){
                product1Map.put(rs.getString("pcode"),rs.getString("pname")); // only one map
            }
    }
}
```

}

Questions -

1. How I can pass multiple queries from "`myspring.xml`" file
2. I want to use existing loadQuery method to load all my queries and put into other Maps i.e. `product2Map`,`order1Map` ,`order2Map`

Comment: What's the point in having those queries in XML? Why not just put them in the code?

Comment: this is existing code and don't want to change structure so thought if it possible to send all queries once from XML file.